# ArrayList index?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

How do you find the index of an int stored inside an ArrayList?

```
public static void thisClass(int max, int[] queue1, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> aList) {

    int[] anArr = Arrays.copyOf(queue1, queue1.length);
    Arrays.sort(anArr);

    ... //sorts ints into groups (ArrayList of ArrayLists)

    }

    int n = 0;
    for (ArrayList<Integer> t : newList) {
        String itemS = "";
        int total = 0;
        for (int index : t) {
            int value = index; //isn't returning index of arrayList - its returning the value
            if (!itemS.isEmpty()) {
                itemS += ", ";
            }
            itemS += index + ":" + value; //want it to output "element Position : element Value
            total += value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an `enhanced for loop`, also referred to as a `foreach` loop. In this loop, there is no index variable defined within the loop; it is simply the value within the array/Iterable itself.

To get the index, you'll have to use a traditional `for` loop:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
myNumbers.add(123);
myNumbers.add(456);
myNumbers.add(789);

for(int i = 0; i < myNumbers.size(); i++) {
    int value = myNumbers.get(i);
    if(value == 789) {
        System.out.println("Found 789 at index " + i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Or he could initialize a variable to 0 and increment it at each iteration, which would be better in the case of a LinkedList, where `get()` is O(N) rather than O(1).

Comment: This seems to make the most sense. However seems i would prefer to use the `for-each loop`, i've just decided not to track the indexes on this occasion. Next time i will be sure to implement a `for loop` instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `indexOf(object)` to get the [index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

Assuming you are using greater than java5. Otherwise you need to create a Integer object instead of primitive int.

Enhanced for loop uses iterator internally, so you couldn't get hold of index.

Answer (score 1):

**-** Use the `indexOf()` method to solve this.......

```
for (ArrayList<Integer> t : newList){

      int index = newList.indexOf(t);

      System.out.println(index);      // Use an array or list to store these 
                                      // index if you want.


}
```

Comment: I also tried this earlier but tracks the indexes of the elements within the arraylists of the arraylist. Not the initial set of indexes before they are sorted/grouped...